# I need the rows to be as colums. How do i do this?

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I'm getting output as rows but I need them to be like columns.

i need the result to be like columns. SID and others as one column and $arr[] and to be other column,both have to be side by side

```
<?php
  $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("dataaa");

  $n=$_POST["SID"];
  print "Entered SID is $n \n";

  $var=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM result WHERE SID ='$n'");

  echo"<table border size=1>";
  echo"<tr><th>SID</th> <th>NAME/th> <th>CLASS</th> 
           <th>Language1</th><th>Language 2</th><th>language3</th><th>MATHEMATICS</th><th>SCIENCE</th><th>SOCIAL STUDIES</th><th>TOTAL MARKS</th><th>PERCENTAGE</th></tr>";
  while ($arr=mysql_fetch_row($var))
   {
    echo "<tr><td>$arr[0]</td> <td>$arr[1]</td> <td>$arr[2]</td><td>$arr[3]</td> <td>$arr[4]</td><td>$arr[5]</td><td>$arr[6]</td><td>$arr[7]</td><td>$arr[8]</td><td>$arr[9]</td><td>$arr[10]</td> </tr>";
   }
   echo"</table>";
   mysql_free_result($var);
   mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Please note the `mysql_*` functions have been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and are **removed as of PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because they have **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE THEM**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: `array_column($array, $key|$index)` ?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php